# How to find the zero roots of $e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, roots, differential

Square root of negative number doesn't exist, so there is no x for which y is zero?

Comment: So I mean, to find the x values where y gets zero.

Comment: An exponential function is never zero.

Comment: You are asking to find the values of $x$ such that $f(x)=e^{-(x^2)}$ are zero?  *sigh*  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complex+roots+of+e%5E(-x%5E2)

Comment: As an additional aside, "*the only root is zero*"... but $e^{-(0)^2}=e^0=1\neq 0$

Comment: The closest you can come to finding a "root", is to notice that as $x$ goes to negative infinity, $e^{-x^2}$ goes to zero. Remember that negative infinity is not a real number, so it isn't a root among the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\exp x > 0$ for any real $x$. Thus no such $x$ such that $\exp (-x^2) = 0$ exists.

If you want complex roots, remember that $\exp z = \cos z + i \sin z$. The complex exponential will be zero when both the sine and cosine are zero for the same $z$.

Comment: You might discuss what happens with complex inputs as well., remember that $\text{exp}(\pi i)=-1<0$

Comment: That last "which doesn't happen without shifting" can be misleading for a newbie in these matter: the exponential, either complex or real, never vanishes (in the real line or in the complex plane).

Comment: "The complex exponential will be zero when both the sine and cosine are zero for the same z." This is misleading at best (and suggests the answerer does not understand complex exponentials at all).

Answer (score 1):

The exponential is nowhere zero because it obeys a power law $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$. Assume $\exp(a)=0$ then $1=\exp(0)=\exp(a-a)=\exp(a)\exp(-a)=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$f: x\mapsto e^{-x^2} $ is even and strictly decreasing at $(0,+\infty)$
and
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f (x)=0$$
$$\implies 0 <f (x)\leq f (0)=1$$

thus no roots.

Comment: $-x^2 \leq 0$ isn't relevant here, simply that the exponential function does not have 0 in its image.